# Placeing code in the right area

Tags: android, listview, dialog

I have a custom dialog with a list view in it and i have been trying to find my next step in my project. Now i know what it is,OnClcikLister for my list view that will open a activity. Now iv look over the net and i don't really know what am looking for.

for some reason i know this code is what am after but also know somethings missing

```
  public class YourClass extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // your stuff here
}
}
```

Now do i open a new class file and add this code to it or do i add this to my main am thinking no because i need to set up a new class to implement it 
And do i also open a new activity for the change from list view to new activity

p.s what is arg0 arg1 etc:

Comment: Are you trying to setup a list and handle the click events for each element? The goal isn't very clear.

Comment: Parameters are in the class documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29

Comment: Ajak yes thats what am after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you extend `ListActivity` (and not `Activity`), you should use [onListItemClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) instead of `onItemClick` Listener.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

}
```

Comment: setListAdapter(adapter); .Does this bit mean i need to make a new class called ^ to bind it to my listactivity class or are they in the same class.I think the class are what i need to learn

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598355/open-multiple-listview-item-click-to-one-class