# Open Multiple Listview Item Click to One Class

Tags: android, listview

Hope you guys can help.

I have a activity which handles all the 10 image button clicks and list view intents. What i am looking to do is have 1 layout for all the list view button clicks. And in this layout call different data to it. When i started this project i had many activitys until a great stack overflow user pointed out that i can make it simpler which i did and made it a lot clear.

```
  package com.example.testtest;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.graphics.Typeface;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.ListView;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  public class Listviewact extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_layout);

    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/AlexBrush-Regular-OTF.otf");
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
  }

   public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    int buttonId = getIntent().getIntExtra("buttonId", 0);
    int buttonIdx = getButtonIdx(buttonId);

    // find and set image according to buttonId
    int imageId = IMAGE_IDS[buttonIdx];        // image to show for given button
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageId);

    // find and set listview imtes according to buttonId
    String[] items = LISTVIEW_DATA[buttonIdx]; // listview items to show for given button
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter adapter) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

// a little helper to map ids to array indices 
// to be able to fetch the correct image and listview data later
private final static int[] BUTTON_IDS = new int[] {
    R.id.imageButton1, 
    R.id.imageButton2, 
    R.id.imageButton3, 
    R.id.imageButton4, 
    R.id.imageButton5, 
    R.id.imageButton6
};

// 6 images
private final static int[] IMAGE_IDS = new int[] {
    R.drawable.bmw,
    R.drawable.ford,
    R.drawable.honda,
    R.drawable.toy,
    R.drawable.vok2,
    R.drawable.ic_launcher
};

// 6 different sets of strings for the listviews
private final static String[][] LISTVIEW_DATA = new String[][] {
    {"First A", "First B", "First C", "First D","First E","First F"},
    {"Second A", "Second B", "Second C"},
    {"Third A", "Third B", "Third C"},
    {"Forth A", "Forth B", "Forth C"},
    {"Fifth A", "Fifth B", "Fifth C"},
    {"Sixth A", "Sixth B", "Sixth C"},
};

// map button id to array index
static private int getButtonIdx(int id) {
    for(int i = 0; i<BUTTON_IDS.length; i++) {
        if (BUTTON_IDS[i] == id) return i;
    }
    return 0;    // should not happen
}
}
```

It would be great if someone can show me how to make a class which i can call all the item clicks from all list views too from my code here.

```
 package com.example.testtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.layout_of_button);
ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
ImageButton btn3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
ImageButton btn4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
ImageButton btn5 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
ImageButton btn6 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);
btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
btn5.setOnClickListener(this);
btn6.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
    // if one of the image buttons is pressed...
    case R.id.imageButton1:
    case R.id.imageButton2:
    case R.id.imageButton3:
    case R.id.imageButton4:
    case R.id.imageButton5:
    case R.id.imageButton6:   
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Listviewact.class);
        // pass ID of pressed button to listview-activity
        intent.putExtra("buttonId", v.getId());  
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    // here you could place handling of other clicks if necessary...        
    }
}

private void setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private ListView getListView() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return null;
 }
 }
```

CHEERS.

http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/705/f6h9.png

Comment: I'm confused on exactly what you want. You want to click on items from the list then what, click a button that will open a new `Activity`, with all of the items that had been clicked on?

Comment: Hi magic what am after is when i click on any of my listview items (all of them) it will open a new layout in which i can reuse with different information so one class for all item clicks.or if am making it harder for my self please let me know.

Comment: You definitely can...I do it all the time. As long as no matter what you click you expect the same `layout`, though it could vary slightly and still be manageable. You could either create a class to store a `static ArrayList` or something similar or send the data though `Intent.extras`

Comment: I have a image in my head what this layout should look like ABOVE IMAGE...If i can i makes sense to have it this way.I would like to have static text and call different text to the side of it.Can you help buddy.

Comment: I don't mind helping but you need to start it and tell us where you are stuck. I have posted an answer that may help to get you started. There are just too many possibilites depending on what exactly you need

Comment: will get right on to it now thanks magic.. star as always

Comment: I added a side-note to my answer that would just clean up your code a bit and, to me, make it more readable but its just a suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want, you could create a class with something like a `static Arraylist` to be appended each time an item is clicked. So create a class something like

```
public class Data class
{
    static ArrayList<String> dataArray = new ArrayList<String>();;

    public Data()
    {
        // empty constructor but could be used if needed
    }
```

Then you can add different `getters/setters` or whatever you need here. When you click on an item you just call something like

```
Data.dataArray.add("stuff");
```

then retrieve items in here in your next `Activity`.

If that is too complicated or more than you need then you can just pass an `ArrayList` or whatever object you need through the `Intent`

[Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Also, just a preference but since all of your `Button`s do the same thing, you can do away with initializing them and setting `listeners` on all of them. In xml just add

```
`android:onClick="someFunctionName"`
```

to each `Button` then use that function name

```
public void someFunctionName(View v) {
switch(v.getId()) {
// if one of the image buttons is pressed...

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Listviewact.class);
    // pass ID of pressed button to listview-activity
    intent.putExtra("buttonId", v.getId());  
    startActivity(intent);
    break;
// here you could place handling of other clicks if necessary...        
}
```

There is also no need for the `case` statements since they all do the same thing and you don't need `implements OnClickListener` in the `Activity` declaration

Comment: Feeling a bit dumb with the code i have been trying to make something happen but am just not getting it. Am thinking what i want to do mite be over my head at the minute as am new to coding. Its hard for me to explane what am after.

Comment: This magic is what i would like to do http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/9373/a7l8.png Now i have the first two images done but its this last class/image where i am finding it hard to code.The last class will have different Text/data/information on the subject from the list view click in second image.That why i asked this question because i dont want to make like 50 class's with there own data/information.I feel there much be a way of having 1 class and just changing view or insert different data to textview.Your code that you give me to start off could be what i need just dont understand it

Comment: Ok, I think I kind of understand what you want. Using a class like in my first example should work. When you click on an item then the associated data is stored in that class. Its hard to say how to set it up as I don't know what you need. You could have different `String`s, int`s, `ArrayList`, `HashMap`...it just depends on what suits your situation. This is a good way to keep the data separate from the presentation level, also

Comment: You mean you were blocked? I don't see why because you don't have that many downvotes and you have accepted answers. The only way that I know of is time and to try and build rep by giving good quality answers. I really don't know why you would be blocked

Comment: Thanks for the tip will try my best.I don't know myself i was just getting on the right track with my project too...cheers

Comment: I'v really tired to unblock my account but its still not having it....Do you know anything else i can do to unblock it magic

Comment: I really don't, sorry. Maybe you can email someone in the help section but I don't know. I still don't understand why its blocked unless you left offensive comments somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `ListView` but not using any of it's callbacks? Here, this is my code that I use for my `ListView`. I'm putting activities in my array, but you could put anything. Modifying the `R.layout.mfd_view` allows you to put whatever you want for each list item. A `Button` if that's what you need. Hope this helps. I'm still learning myself.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {
String fragmentBackStack;
MyMapHandler handler;
OnViewSelectedListener mListener;

/**
 * An array of POJOs used to hold the info about the fragments we'll be
 * swapping between This should be inserted into an array adapter of some
 * sort before being passed onto ListAdapter
 */
private static final ViewDetails[] ACTIVITY_DETAILS = {
        new ViewDetails(R.string.action_largeTach,
                R.string.largeTach_description, LargeTachActivity.class),
        new ViewDetails(R.string.action_map, R.string.map_description,
                MyMapHandler.class),
        new ViewDetails(R.string.action_navigation,
                R.string.navigation_description, NavigationActivity.class),
        new ViewDetails(R.string.action_raceMode,
                R.string.raceMode_description, RaceModeActivity.class),
        new ViewDetails(R.string.action_settings,
                R.string.settings_description, SettingsFragment.class),
        new ViewDetails(R.string.action_extraInfo,
                R.string.extraInfo_description, ExtraInfoActivity.class) };

/**
 * @author PyleC1
 * 
 *         A POJO that holds a class object and it's resource info
 */
public static class ViewDetails {
    private final Class<? extends Activity> viewActivity;
    private int titleId;
    private int descriptionId;

    /**
     * @param titleId
     *            The resource ID of the string for the title
     * @param descriptionId
     *            The resource ID of the string for the description
     * @param activityClass
     *            The fragment's class associated with this list position
     */
    ViewDetails(int titleId, int descriptionId,
            Class<? extends Activity> viewActivity) {

        super();
        this.titleId = titleId;
        this.descriptionId = descriptionId;
        this.viewActivity = viewActivity;
    }

    public Class<? extends Activity> getViewActivity() {
        return viewActivity;
    }
}

/**
 * @author PyleC1
 * 
 *         Extends the ArrayAdapter class to support our custom array that
 *         we'll insert into the ListAdapter so the user can pick between
 *         MFD screens at boot time.
 */
private static class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ViewDetails> {
    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, ViewDetails[] activities) {
        super(context, R.layout.mfd_view, R.id.mfdTitle, activities);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        MFDView mfdView;

        if (convertView instanceof MFDView) {
            mfdView = (MFDView) convertView;
        } else {
            mfdView = new MFDView(getContext());
        }

        ViewDetails details = getItem(position);

        mfdView.setTitleId(details.titleId);
        mfdView.setDescriptionId(details.descriptionId);

        return mfdView;
    }
}

public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    ListAdapter listAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getActivity(),
            ACTIVITY_DETAILS);
    setListAdapter(listAdapter);

    try {
        mListener = (OnViewSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnViewSelectedListener!");
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

public interface OnViewSelectedListener {
    public void onViewSelected(Class<? extends Activity> activityClass);
}

public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    ViewDetails details = (ViewDetails) getListAdapter().getItem(position);

    mListener.onViewSelected(details.viewActivity);
}
}
```

Note that whatever activity calls this fragment must implement the `OnViewSelectedListener` interface. If you added this to your main activity as a subclass, this wouldn't be required. The `public void onListItemClick(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3)` callback is fine. You just swap fragments or call activities from inside there.

Comment: At the moment all is well when i click on any one of my imagebutton the activity open fine and the listview is there and works its from here i would like to open a new activity/layout from all the listview items that have been clciked.if am missing something please let me know cheers downrangefuture...we will get there in the end;)

Comment: So you're trying to make a new dynamic layout from what the user selected? You'd probably need to put a bundle together and send it off to the new activity. Then in the layout for the new activity, set the view containers up with 0dp and various `android:layout_weight` values set. Then you could just show/hide the fragments at `onCreate(Bundle)` in the new activity. Be sure you call `setContentView(int)` before you start making calls to the `FragmentManager`.